# "New..." alternative in DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a `DropDownListFor` in a form in which I list all currently available options. Now, I want to provide an "New..." alternative. Selecting this would display a new textbox in which a new alternative can be created.

I have added the alternative, bound some javascript to display the additional form (generated with `EditorFor`). What remains is how to validate the input. Do I have to create a custom model binder for this scenario? Essentially what I want is either an existing value is chosen from the drop down, *or* all properties in the additional fields are filled in according to validation rules.

I'm using C# for the backend, though I doubt that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fetch the next dropdown with ajax you need to bind that input to the jquery validiation framework

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#myform");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. However, it does not work. The new inputs that are moved into the form are not subject to validation, and the "New..." value in the drop down does not pass validation. It needs to somehow be excluded from the validation.

Comment: Found out that the inputs have to be inside the `<form>` tag when the document ready event is fired. Put them there and then moved them out and hid them afterwards, so now they are validated. Now I just need to have different validation rules for the drop-down.